# How do I stop having the same "community members have suggested a similar question" pop-up?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, post-notices

I have posted a question here: [Is it possible to run a script on power button press with systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563603/is-it-possible-to-run-a-script-on-power-button-press-with-systemd) and every time I come back to this page I have a

> Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem
>       Does this answer your question?
>       How to change Power button shutdown action to run a script under systemd (2 answers)
>        Yes  No
>       (Private feedback)

That I answered "no" several times but keep popping up again and again, it there a way to get definitively rid of it ?

To be frank this is not really a big issue but it is quite frustrating answering the same question again and again.

Comment: The old notice didn't have Yes/No buttons, just a link to edit your question. If this new functionality doesn't work, I assume it must be a bug.

Comment: @Glorfindel is correct. Once you dismiss a question as a potential duplicate, it shouldn't show up for you anymore. I will look into it, thanks for reporting this.

Comment: @Luuklag voted this question as duplicate. Automatically it becomes a comment "does this answer your question?". That's a bit silly. The referred question is duplicate, as luuklag noticed, but obviously (not having answers) it doesn't answer the question. This makes the response a bit blunt (and very ironic given that this question is about the annoying questions about duplicate, 'does this answer?' questions). Also, it is placing words in Luuklag's mouth that he did not make himselve (he just voted duplicate and not said that question). Before this was a comment like 'possible duplicate....'.

Comment: @YaakovEllis you might want to look into the change of the message placed in the comments when somebody votes for closing. It is very confusing. It asks for 'does this answer...?' but as far as I understood that is not defining a duplicate question (or can duplicate questions be repeatedly asked as long as there is no answer?).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus one issue per post please. I can't track separate bug reports or feature requests in comments