# Repeatedly shown possible duplicate checkboxes on my question after dismissing it

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

[My question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379303/323179) currently has some duplicate votes, but I can't seem to get the message to go away and stay that way:

[image: Screenshot of private feedback shown every time a duplicate close vote has been cast on an OP's question]

> A community member has suggested a similar question that may solve your problem.
>
> Does this answer your question?
>
> [Question Title] (N answers)    [Yes/no radio buttons]
>
> Submit
>
> (Private feedback for you)

I checked it once and submitted, I did it again when another duplicate question was offered and now I have to do it again. It vanishes after I check it and submit but then later comes back, probably in response to getting a new close vote, as [specified in the original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) (even when it's the same dupe target). I also edited my question at every point during this and that didn't do anything to dismiss it.

Assuming that I'm right, a user may have to dismiss this message five times per close cycle (one flag plus four close votes). More if the votes age out but people keep on casting more.

This was annoying and confusing for me, so I can't imagine what someone who doesn't know Stack Exchange would feel. They certainly wouldn't know that more people are casting close votes, and the message unexpectedly returning doesn't really help with that either. It just looks broken.

Can't this be made to respect the fact that I've already dismissed it, and also edited?

Comment: The temptation is to vote to close this post as a duplicate, only to see if the behaviour you described is repeatable.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes Would you mind if I cast my vote to close your post as a duplicate?

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні [My linked one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379303/323179)? Sure, if you agree to retract the vote before someone else closes it, lol.

Comment: No, I meant *this new question/request/bug*. If you edit and dismiss the warning, then the defect/anomaly is limited to that linked post. Of course I'll retract the close vote if you confirm the message disappears.

Comment: Well you would need someone else to close vote to be able to prove much of anything with this question so I think it would be better to cast a vote on the other one (assuming you weren't one of the existing votes there).

Comment: I don't think voting to close the first question as a duplicate will work because the review was completed 22 hours ago in favour of keeping it open, so congratulations on that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/82945

Comment: It's not affected by the close queue idt because there used to be a third vote that happened after the vote from that review. So I think it would work on my linked question, at the expense of putting it back into the queue (though retracting it would probably take it out again?). Otherwise you would need to get some people to do a close vote party, since you're going to need more than one vote to replicate it here.

Comment: It now sounds too messy and complicated for me. Anyway, it was only an idea=experiment.

Comment: Yes, I've experienced this a few times before. The message is re-shown with each new close vote (even if it's for the same dup-target) and most likely with flags too.

Comment: This is a reoccurring bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342500/282094

Comment: @Rob I don't think that's the same bug. In the linked question, the OP says that the message reappears every time they refresh the page. Here (and what I also noticed before), it reappears with each new close vote.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine These are closer duplicates: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345191/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343055/how-do-i-stop-having-the-same-community-members-have-suggested-a-similar-questi?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1148982_343055